# Changing keyboard symbols used throughout macOS?

Tags: macos, keyboard

I'm new to macOS after a decade using of using Windows, and whenever I view shortcut keys anywhere in macOS I get confused.

Is there a way to somehow replace these symbols across macOS, for example, by changing themes or system fonts, so that I might end up with something like below?

[image]

*Desired symbols shown on right*

Comment: Shift and Control are universal - they exist on Linux, Windows and Mac.  The other two, Command and Option are exclusively Mac with Option being shared with Alt.  Why would you want to alter them - they're native to the platform?

Comment: A comment and not answer, because it doesn't answer your question, but hopefully will help you out. Some people (like myself) have switched to mac after far longer than a decade of using Windows. Better yet, a lot of us didn't switch completely and use both of the systems. Get used to it and soon enough you will be ok. You will visit sites (like SO) which will use the macos specific symbols and nobody will translate them for you. Other, non-system apps, will use those symbols and will ignore your system changes.  You will save yourself a lot of time, grief and confusion by learning those.

Comment: Nicely written comment @Krystian, I got inclined to include it as part of the answer and have attributed you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The said symbols are deeply integrated into the Operating System. Some of them like  <kbd>⌘</kbd>  (**Command**) and  <kbd>⌥</kbd>  (**Option**) are exclusive to the Apple platform.

It is in no way possible neither is it recommended to replace them in a system wide manner.

What is recommend to a Mac newbie, is to print a keyboard shortcuts cheat-sheet and pin it close to the desk. A few days in, and it will become second nature. A good one can be downloaded [here](http://macmost.net/downloads/MacMostKeyboardShortcutsSierra.pdf) courtesy of [MacMost](https://macmost.com).

You can print a large version of just the symbol guide and pin it until it is memorized.

[image]

**Update**: I got inclined to update this answer after reading [Krystian's](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/16263/krystian) nicely written comment on the question. Quoting it below:

> Some people (like myself) have switched to mac after far longer than a decade of using Windows. Better yet, a lot of us didn't switch completely and use both of the systems. Get used to it and soon enough you will be ok. You will visit sites (like SO) which will use the macos specific symbols and nobody will translate them for you. Other, non-system apps, will use those symbols and will ignore your system changes. You will save yourself a lot of time, grief and confusion by learning those.

Comment: It would be impossible to replace the glyphs with images. Nice answer.

Comment: This would confuse the OP even more :) That's a symbol for backspace and not delete. To use it as delete you will have to use Fn.